# Contact form 7 email using SMTP

Tags: wordpress, email, phpmailer, contact-form-7

I created a web site using WordPress.
I added Contact Form 7 in my side bar. 
After I filled the fields in the contact form, and click the Send button, I got an error message in a red box:

> There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again
>   later.

I did not install phpmailer. I wrote a test php (testemail.php showed below). When I visit `http://www.MyDomainName.com.au/testemail.php` in the browser, it shows whole codes of the testemail.php!

Do I have to install a phpmailer plugin, for example, Easy WP SMTP?
What is the problem in testemail?
Finally how to make my contact form working?

The testemail.php code:

```
function sendMail($request) {
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = mail@MyDomainName.com.au;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'mail@MyDomainName.com.au';
$mail->Password = 'myPassword';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->setFrom('mail@MyDomainName.com.au', 'Title');
$mail->addAddress(xxx@hotmail.com);
$mail->addReplyTo('mail@MyDomainName.com.au');

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = '$Something';

$mail->Body = 'The body of the email';

$mail->AltBody = 'Alternative'; // this is mostly sent to your own mail

if(!$mail->send()) {
echo 'Message could not be sent.';
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo 'Message has been sent';
}
}
```

Comment: Install any SMTP plugin and add your server or gmail smtp details in it. It will working fine

Comment: `Host` should be the host name of your SMTP server, not an email address, and it's probably not in your domain. When you say "it shows whole codes", do you mean it shows the PHP source code, or that you see lots of debug output? You have debug output turned on with `SMTPDebug = 4`, which will cause that.

Comment: WordPress already uses PHPMailer for its `wp_mail()` function, no need to include it again: https://gist.github.com/butlerblog/c5c5eae5ace5bdaefb5d. Also, I'm not sure why you assume that you need to install the PHPMailer library in order for CF 7 to work O.o

Comment: Thank all of you.  "it shows whole codes", I mean it shows the PHP source code. Because the Contact Form 7 doesn't work, The support staff of the host suggested me to put the testmail.php in my web site and tested it. They also mentioned the PHPMailer. I am new to wordpress and have no idea with PHP. Where is the PHPMailer in the WordPress? Does Contact Form 7 calls the wp_mail() in the PHPMailer? Where to configure the host for the WordPress default PHPMailer? Thank you again.